# atlassian-plugin.xml contains a definition of component-import. This is not allowed when Atlassian-Plugin-Key is set

Tags: jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

This is what I get when I run `atlas-create-jira-plugin` followed by `atlas-create-jira-plugin-module` selecting option `1:  Component Import`.

The problem is that all tutorial examples appear to have plugin descriptor generated by old SDK version (that won't deploy with newer versions of SDK/Jira at all), which do not feature `Atlassian-Plugin-Key`, so I can't find my way to import a component.

I'm using SDK 6.2.3 and Jira 7.1.1.

Any hint - how to get this sorted out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found answer here: https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins

It looks like I've somehow been missing that `Atlassian-Plugin-Key` can be omitted, and it must be done when you need to import components.

This key just tells spring not to 'transform' plugin's Spring configuration, which must happen as part of components import process..

Answer (score 8):

anonymous is correct.  The old way of doing things was to to put the `<component-import>` tag in your `atlassian-plugin.xml`.  The new way and also recommended is to use [Atlassian Spring Scanner](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-spring-scanner). When you create your add-on using `atlas-jira-create-plugin` and your `pom.xml` has the `<Atlassian-Plugin-Key>` tag and the dependencies `atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation` and `atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime` then you are using the new way.

If you have both the dependencies, you are using Atlassian Spring Scanner version 1.x.  If you only have `atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation` then you are using version 2.x.

You don't have to omit/comment out `Atlassian-Plugin-Key` in your `pom.xml` and you don't have to put `component-import` in your `atlassian-plugin.xml`.

For example, you want to add licensing for your add-on and need to import the component `PluginLicenseManager`.  You just go straight to the code and your constructor might look like this:

```
@Autowired
public MyMacro(@ComponentImport PluginLicenseManager licenseManager) {
    this.licenseManager = licenseManager;
}
```

And your class like this:

```
@Scanned
public class MyMacro implements Macro {
```

If memory serves me right, be sure to check for `null` because sometimes Atlassian Spring Scanner can't inject a component.  I think on version 1, writing an `@EventListener`, it could not inject a `ConversionContext`.  But when writing a Macro, it was able to inject a `ConversionContext`.

Answer (score 5):

According to
https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-spring-scanner

`component-import` is not needed. You can replace it by `@ComponentImport` annotation in your Java.